# React Router renders only after refresh

Tags: react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

i'm trying to create a web app with react redux and router, and i'm getting a wierd behaviour, the Router is rendering only on refresh.
that my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ModalProvider } from './modal/modalContext';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import BoardUser from "./components/BoardUser";
import BoardModerator from "./components/BoardModerator";
import BoardAdmin from "./components/BoardAdmin";
import DataService from "./services/data.service";
import { logout } from "./actions/auth";
import { clearMessage } from "./actions/message";
import { setDc } from "./actions/dc";
import { history } from "./helpers/history";
import simplidc_logo from "./images/dns-24px.svg"
import DetailedRackCard from './components/detailed_rack_card'

const App = () => {
  const [showModeratorBoard, setShowModeratorBoard] = useState(false);
  const [showAdminBoard, setShowAdminBoard] = useState(false);

  const { user: currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen((location) => {
      dispatch(clearMessage()); // clear message when changing location
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      setShowModeratorBoard(currentUser.roles.includes("ROLE_MODERATOR"));
      setShowAdminBoard(currentUser.roles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  useEffect(() => {
    DataService.getDevices().then(
      (devicesResponse) =>{
        DataService.getRacks().then(
          (racksResponse) =>{
            dispatch(setDc(DataService.getDc(racksResponse,devicesResponse)));
          }
        )
      }
    )
}, [dispatch]);
  const logOut = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <ModalProvider>
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
            SimpliDC
            <img
                        alt=""
                        src={simplidc_logo}
                        width="30"
                        height="30"
                    />
          </Link>
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>

            {showModeratorBoard && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/mod"} className="nav-link">
                  Moderator Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}

            {showAdminBoard && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                  Admin Board
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}

            {currentUser && (
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                  User
                </Link>
              </li>
            )}
          </div>

          {currentUser ? (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                  {currentUser.username}
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={logOut}>
                  LogOut
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                  Login
                </Link>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                  Sign Up
                </Link>
              </li>
            </div>
          )}
        </nav>
        <input className="" type="text" placeholder="Type any vaule to search in the DC..."/>

        <div className="container mt-3">

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
            <Route path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
            <Route path="/rack/:id" component={DetailedRackCard}/>
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
    </ModalProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**and i found something wierd happening while looking in the react dev tools on the Router component. this is the location in state after refresh:**
[image]

**and this is the same object after i click a route (login):**
[image]

i'm desprate for help....
yes, that my only router in the whole app.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `state` of the `<Router/>` comes from the `history` prop which your are providing.  You are not modifying that `history` properly.  The bad mutation will be somewhere in another file.  It seems like you are calling `history.push()` with the entire action object instead of just the `action.location` property.

Using the `<Router/>` component with a custom `history` prop is an advanced design pattern that you generally want to avoid unless absolutely necessary.  I don't think it's necessary here, at least not for the code in this particular file.

I would recommend using a `<BrowserRouter/>` (or `<HashRouter/>`, etc. instead.  If you do that, you'll need some other way to address the `history.listen` subscription (sidenote: you want to use a cleanup function to stop listening when the component unmounts).

You can use a `useEffect` hook to respond to changes in the location which you access from the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(clearMessage()); // clear message when changing location
}, [location, dispatch]);
```

If you don't want to clear the message on the first render, you can add some additional checks before dispatching.  You can potentially use a [`usePrevious`](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/) custom hook or something like it. Here I am using `useRef` to store the previous location.  The initial value for the ref is the `location` from `useLocation`, so on the first render they will be equal.

```
const location = useLocation();

const locRef = useRef(location);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(locRef.current, location);
  // will be equal on first render
  if (locRef.current !== location) {
    dispatch(clearMessage());
  }
  locRef.current = location;
}, [location, dispatch]);
```

You could modify this to look at just the `pathname` if you want.

Comment: Thanks! i switch to BrowserRouter and now it's working great!